# Asp.net website as Sharepoint subsite

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2013

I have a Sharepoint site, for example http://sharepoint. 
And I have an asp.net website, now it's working fine on http://sharepoint:85/website, same domain, different ports.

I need this website to work in the same port, like http://sharepoint/website. It must not work under Sharepoint or something, just need to share the address.

I tried Add application to sharepoint site in IIS manager, but http://sharepoint/website is showing an error "Server Error in '/website' Application".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. My method with Add application to site in IIS manager is fine. With `<customErrors mode="Off">` in web.config page shows an error Default Role Provider could not be found.
Then in web.config found

```
    <roleManager>
       <providers>
       <clear/>
     </providers>
   </roleManager>
```

Deleted `<clear/>` row, now site is working.